# Blank notification appears without any code call

Tags: android, android-notifications

i experience pretty weird thing in my android app. In some unknown for me cases sometimes blank notification apperas in notification bar, without any title, body and with default gray color. The only filled thing is icon, which is my default application icon(from manifest).

There is only one place in project when i create notification manually - intent service that sends data via rest api. Notification have his own icon (different than default), color, text, progressbar and works fine when service is running. I have not configured any Cloud Messaging or push notification in this project.

I spent a lot of time and i have no idea why blank notification described above appears. I will be grateful for any hint how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am also facing this issue, when the app is closed that time notification will appear like this. I am resolved this issue in server side.

There are two types of messages in FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging):

1. Display Messages: These messages trigger the `onMessageReceived()` callback only when your app is in foreground
2. Data Messages: Theses messages trigger the `onMessageReceived()` callback even if your app is in foreground/background/killed

Firebase team have not developed a UI to send `data-messages` to your devices, yet.

**refer this link to achieve**

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

And the following headers:

**Key:** `Content-Type`, **Value:** `application/json`

**Key:** `Authorization`, **Value:** `key=<your-server-key>`

**Body using topics:**

```
{
    "to": "/topics/my_topic",
    "data": {
        "my_custom_key" : "my_custom_value",
        "other_key" : true
     }
}
```

**Or to send it to specific devices:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "my_custom_key" : "my_custom_value",
        "other_key" : true
     },
    "registration_ids": ["{device-token}","{device2-token}","{device3-token}"]
}
```

**NOTE:** Be sure you're not adding JSON key notification

**NOTE:** To get your server key, you can find it in the firebase console: Your project -> settings -> Project settings -> Cloud messaging -> Server Key

Comment: I'm not using GCM, FCM or any other push notification service, just local notifications sent by NotificationManager